# Turn off syncing in Lightroom CC

Tags: lightroom, adobe

I want to turn off the automatic sync to the Creative Cloud of photos.
I do not want to upload a single photo to the cloud.

I tried turning it off by following the answer in [this question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2437404) but it didn't work even after restarting the computer.

How can I turn off it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong software, as the basic concept of Lightroom CC on all platforms is based on syncing *everything* to the cloud.

If you want do have an offline Workflow, you need to use [Lightroom Classic CC](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom-classic/lightroom-cc-vs-lightroom-classic.html) *. If you want to have control what is synced to the cloud, you can also connect *one* Lightroom Classic Catalogue to Lightroom CC and sync specific collections, with the following caveats when importing into Classic:

- Only smart previews, not full-size photos are synced
- No keyword syncing
- No syncings of color marks (as Lightroom CC doesn't have them)

If you import your pictures to Lightroom CC (e. g. on a mobile), the full-size picture is synced back to your Desktop Lightroom Classic. Edits are synced both ways.

* *This application was called Lightroom CC some time ago, but Adobe decided to rename it as they launched the new cloud based ecosystem that evolved from Lightroom Mobile and is now called Lightroom CC - much to the confusion of everyone.*

Comment: I though Lightroom CC was basically like the new version of Lightroom Classic, which also automatically updates with new changes. 
Lightroom Classic looks so old :D

Comment: No, they share a common code base (Adobe Camera Raw, also shared by Photoshop) and have probably a common ancestry. But they're independent applications with different approaches to the photo management workflow. They can talk to each other with the limitations outlined above.